# Database scheme in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am having in greatest nightmare on deciding a database schema ! Recently signed up to my first freelancer project.

It has a user registration, and there is pretty decent requirements on user table as follows:

```
- name
- password
- email
- phone
- is_active
- email_verified
- phone_verified
- is_admin
- is_worker
- is_verified
- has_payment
- last_login
- created_at
```

Now am at huge confusion to decide whether to put everything under a single table or split things, as still I need to add few more fields like

```
- token
- otp ( may be in future )
- otp_limit ( may be in future ) // rate limiting
```

And may be something more in future when there is an update: I am afraid that, if there is an future update with new field to table then how to add that again if it's a single table.

And if I split things will that cause performance issue ? As most of the fields are moderately used on the webapp.

How can I decide?

Comment: What is your database narrative? Who are the users, what is product/service/campaign, what metric do you track? Essentially, what is the business purpose i.e., *Customers purchase multiple Products/Services supplied by multiple Supplier/Vendors in one of our many Stores to complete multiple Sales Orders on different dates*? This should guide design.

Comment: Its just a portfolio website, each user can have a portfolio of various stocks ! User gets register and they choose stocks to watch and thats it !

Answer (score 0):

Your initial aim should be to create a model that is in 3rd Normal Form (3NF). Once you have that, if you then need to move away from a strict 3NF model in order to effectively handle some specific operational requirements/challenges then that's fine - as long as you know what your doing.

A working/simplified definition of whether a model is in 3NF is that all attributes that can be uniquely identified by the same key should be in the same table.

So all attributes of a user should be in the same table (as long as they have a 1:1 relationship with the User ID).

I'm not sure why adding new columns to a table in the future is worrying you - this should not affect a well-designed application. Obviously altering/dropping columns is a different matter.

Comment: I was worried because, if we have users like millions and then if i need to add a new column wont that create a fuzz ?

Comment: How will splitting the table help that? You will still have millions of records in each user table

Comment: But it wont affect the primary table right

Comment: I don’t understand the point you are trying to make. If you have 2 user tables both with the same number of records then the impact/effort of adding a column is the same, regardless of which table you add it to. Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, design database according to your business or project use case and narrative in mind. Essentially, you need a relational model of `Users`, `Portfolios`, and `Stocks` where *Users can have many Portfolios and each Portfolio can contain many Stocks*. If you need to track `Registrations` or `Logins`, add that to schema where *Users can have multiple Registrations or Logins*. Doing so, you simply add rows with corresponding `UserID` and not columns.

Also, consider best practices:

1. **Use Lookup Tables**: For static (or rarely changed) data shared across related entities, incorporate lookup tables in relation model like `Tickers` (with its ID referenced as foreign key in `Stocks`). Anything that regularly changes at specific level (i.e., user-level) should be stored in that table. Remember database tables should not resemble spreadsheets with repeated static data stored within it.
2. **Avoid Data Elements in Columns**: Avoid wide-formatted tables where you store data elements in columns. Tables with hundreds of suffixed or dated columns is indicative of this design. Doing this you avoid clearly capturing *Logins* data and force a re-design such as `ALTER` commands for new column with every new instance. Always normalize data for storage, efficiency, and scaling needs.

   | UserID | Login1 | Login2 | Login3 | ... |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 10001 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
   | 10002 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
   | 10003 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
3. **Application vs Data Centric Design**: Depending on your use case, try to not build database with specific application in mind but as a generalized solution for all users including business personnel, CEOs to regular staff, and maybe even data scientists. Therefore, avoid short names, abbreviations (like `otp`), industry jargon, etc. Everything should be clear and straightforward as much as possible.

   Additionally, avoid any application or script that makes structural changes to database like creating temp tables or schemas on the fly. There is a debate if business logic should be contained in database or run in specific application. Usually data should be handled between database and application. Keep in mind , MySQL is a powerful (though free), enterprise, server-level RDBMS and not a throwaway file-level, small scale system.
4. **Maintain Consistent Signature**: Pick a naming convention and stick to it throughout the design (i.e., camelcase, snake case, plurals). There is a big debate if you should prefix objects `tbl`, `vw`, and `sp`. One strategy is to name data objects by its content and procedures/functions by its action. Always avoid reserved words and special characters and spaces in names.
5. **Always Document**: While very tedious for developers, document every object, functionality, and extension and annotate table and fields for definitions. MySQL supports [`COMMENTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) in `CREATE` statements for tables and fields. And use `#` or `--` for comments in stored procedures or triggers.

Once designed and in production, databases should rarely (if not ever) be restructured. So carefully think of *all* possibilities and scenarios beforehand with your use case. Do not dismiss the very important database design step. Good luck!